# why ubuntu os is too slow

Tags: server, 13.04, performance, 13.10

Specifications:

samsung mini laptop

model code NP-N100S-E01
             N100S-E01
RAM= 4GB

HARD DISC=320 GB

PROCESSOR= INTEL ATOM PROCESSOR

ATOM PROCESSOR N2100

I am installing Ubuntu 13.x OS but it is too slow , if I give any command it works after 2 to 3 min. If I can close any windows, it will close step by step slowly slowly. Why is it this much slow? This is the 3rd or 4th time I am installing Ubuntu on my laptop and I always had this problem. Please help me with your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really tell what the problem is from you description, if English is not your first language I suggest a good spell checker to help with some of the editing. Try [Lubuntu 13.04](http://Lubuntu.net), it is based on Ubuntu 13.04, but is lighter on your computer's  resources. I have never had a problem. Takes about maybe >15-20 minutes to do a full clean install. Also the community here is pretty awesome, and the things you do in Ubuntu can be done in Lubuntu. It helped me out with my laptop problems (Mine is a HP Compaq nx6325 with AMD Turion64 x2 mobile processor.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the idea of testing different Ubuntu flavors as Live media PRIOR to installing.

As you say you have a Samsung Mini, I guess - this being a netbook - it doesn't have a optical unit so you're only left with the option of LiveUSB.

Download some/all of Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu and try each one as LiveUSB.
See how responsive is each of them on your system as Live media and based on this real usage test choose in the end the one that works ok on your system.

Good luck and let us know how it works!

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Lubuntu and Xubuntu successfully on the same hardware.  The performance, although not amazing, is more than acceptable.

Try installing Lubuntu or Xubuntu on your computer and see if that helps.  Better still, try the live media before you install as suggested.  Keep in mind though:  A proper install will be more responsive than a live boot.